# Flash Object - Stretching and Compressing Aspect Ratio

Tags: html, flash, object, tags, aspect-ratio

Is there a way to NOT preserve aspect ratio in Flash Object (like preserveAspectRatio="none" in SVG)? I want to stretch and compress swf objects.

In this example "no_idea" means param. I don't know if there is another method...

```
<object data="flash.swf">
<param name="no_idea" value="none">
</object>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,  you can use the `scale` parameter:

```
<param name="scale" value="exactfit" />
```

Exact fit will make the swf fit in the dimensions of the container, ignoring aspect.

Other options include:

1. `default` - this will scale the swf so it shows everything keeping aspect
2. `noborder` - this will scale the swf so it fills the container, cropping content if needed but keeping aspect.
3. `noscale` - this leaves it up to the swf to do any resizing

Keep in mind though, I think the code in the SWF itself has the option to override these settings.

For a list of all the parameter options, see the [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html)